# Como paso un string a otro JFrame Form en Java pulsando un botón?

Tags: java, java-swing

Este es mi boton con el string que quiero pasar

```
 private void jButton_DetallesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        String Nombrepj = jLabel_Img.getText();
        
        new DatosCampeon().setVisible(true);
        setVisible(false);
    }
```

y quiero pasar ese dato a otra vista(JFrame Form) para usarlo

```
public class DatosCampeon extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static String NombreUsuario;
    public static String LvlCuenta;
    /**
     * Creates new form DatosCampeon
     */
    public DatosCampeon() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        jPanelUsuario.setVisible(false);
        
    }
```

Por favor necesito ayuda urgente, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Has probado usando herencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es extraer un string de un JFrame a otro pulsando un boton puedes hacer lo siguiente para llamarlo:

Primero en donde esta el boton mande a llamar un metodo `getText()` que puse en el JFrame de donde quieres obtener el String, y después añadiendolo a tu `String`  guardandolo como una variable `public static String Texto`:

```
 public static String Texto;

 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    
    Ventana_2 vent = new Ventana_2();
     Texto = vent.getTxt();
     this.txt1.setText(Texto);
}
```

En la ventana donde esta el texto que quieres traer agregue el getText directamente para que tu manipularas donde obtenerlo, ademas de tambien agregar la variable `public String txtEnviar;`:

```
 public String txtEnviar;

 public String getTxt(){

    txtEnviar = this.txt2.getText();
    return txtEnviar;
}
```

Eso fue lo que pude Entender con lo que requieres, si no es el caso entonces trata de especificar mejor el problema, aun no tengo la reputacion para comentar, Suerte!

Comment: 10 puntos más y podrás comentar. Gracias por tus aportes. Bueno, ya puedes :)

Comment: Lo acabo de notar. Gracias!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que decea es crear un nuevo JFrame (DatosCampeon) y que inicie con los datos, en este caso el string:

```
private void jButton_DetallesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    DatosCampeon DC = new DatosCampeon();
    DC.NombreUsuario =  jLabel_Img.getText();
    DC.setVisible(true);
    setVisible(false);
}
```

> O puede poner directamente los datos que quiere pasar en el constructor :

```
public class DatosCampeon extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public String NombreUsuario;
public String LvlCuenta;
/**
 * Creates new form DatosCampeon
 */
public DatosCampeon(String nombre,String lvl) {
    initComponents();
     NombreUsuario = nombre; LvlCuenta = lvl;
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    jPanelUsuario.setVisible(false);
    
}
```

> En ese caso el código del botón sería el siguiente:

```
   private void jButton_DetallesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    DatosCampeon DC = new DatosCampeon(jLabel_Img.getText(),"" /*Lvl Cuenta */);
    
    DC.setVisible(true);
    setVisible(false);
}
```